# Handling CoreLocation service reply

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

In my app i am using CoreLocation services to access current Location. For accessing the current location in iPhone the Location service must be turned ON in settings. If not it alerts the user as

"Turn On Location Services to Allow "helloworldApp" to determine Your Location" and choices for this alert message are settings and cancel.

Now how can i handle this reply from CoreLocation framework. Whether user clicks on the settings button or cancel button?

Please Suggest.

Any help would be appreciated !

-Sathiya

Answer (score 0):

Query CLLocationManager for locationServicesEnabled property. If this is disabled, you can count on either the user having rejected your request or he disabling it on settings.